# FullCalendar - Day View editable area

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

[image: Editable area]
.
I use FullCalendar.
In Day View I would like to be able to specify an editable area - as shown in white in the screenshot between 13:30 and 20:00.
So I should not be able to drag a session outside this area or modify the brown session (outside of the white area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [original issue](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=144), I'm now using [background events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) to manage the visual effect of editable areas.